# converting plain text to html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails 3 app receives emails. Some of them are plain text. When the app displays them to the user I want them to be properly formatted. In other word I want to encode plain text into html. For example: "Hello\n\nHello" =>

Hello

Hello

(or something like it).

Of course I can write my own 4 lines of code but I am sure those 4 lines have already be written, tested and wrapped in some nice method call.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format is a simple start, you can explore redcloth, rdiscout etc. for more advanced requirements.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442375/escape-non-html-tags-in-plain-text-convert-plain-text-to-html/22442376#22442376

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your text in a  [Pre tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp):

```
<%= content_tag('pre', "Hello\n\nHello") %>
```

Comment: Yes.  Newline characters in a `<pre>` tag will be rendered in the browser.

Comment: The question is how  to convert to html, not how to display plain text properly

Comment: There is no direct conversion for plain text to html. The <pre> tag preserves text formatting.

Answer (score 23):

I know I'm a little late, but I actually think the proper solution to this, at least within Rails, is to leverage the [`simple_format` helper method provided from `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format).

Answer (score 2):

Using `#html_safe`, let me explain with an example:

If in your controller the variable is:

```
@str = "<h1>Hi</h1>"
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= @str.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Batkins has the right answer, which should be accepted.
if someone who is still looking,

Converting plain text to HTML

```
<%= simple_format("plain text") %>
```

Converting HTML to proper plain text

```
text.html_safe
```

The simple_format is [TextHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) module so you if you want to use simple_format method in controller

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
render :text => "bla bla bla"
```

it be useful
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Rendering/render