# Escape non HTML tags from plain text

Tags: html-sanitizing

I need to escape non HTML tags to convert a plain text into a valid HTML, how can I do that?

I'm using ruby, but I may use an external tool

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CGI::escapeHTML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escapeHTML) to escape all special HTML characters so you can safely paste the content into HTML as text.

Comment: I want to escape only invalid HTML tags, like `<blah>`

Comment: That’s not really a good idea. The HTML standard is constantly evolving, making it difficult to pinpoint a set of valid elements. There is also a standard that allows defining custom elements, adding to the set of valid elements. And technically, most browsers will allow you do specify *any* element name and won’t fail but assume some standard behavior. You can take a look at [`escapeElement`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escapeElement) though which will escape a set of elements.

Comment: That's actually what gmail and other webmails do, and I'm building my webmail app... here is what I got for the moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442375/escape-non-html-tags-in-plain-text-convert-plain-text-to-html/22442376#22442376